# How to make a calendar with phases of the moon?

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I am creating an Android application and want help to create a calendar with moon phases, anyone can post the code

Comment: You should post some of your code, no matter the quality in order to get help. If you need it, check out the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I ever done a simple project that help to convert from a specified solar date to lunar date, follow some function on DateCalc.java on this project: https://github.com/minhhuy150894/Time-Calc

Answer (score 0):

Here is some source code in (msvc) C, Python3, bash to generate lunar planetary calenders in htm,pdf,ps,txt  https://github.com/moshahmed/astronomy or you can use the output: 10 year calenders (2018 to 2028) https://github.com/moshahmed/astronomy/tree/master/calendar-py/bundle